# How to test ASP.NET code-behind

Tags: asp.net, nunit, code-behind, functional-testing

We are in the process of re-writing legacy code, but currently I am wondering how to test code-behind methods.

Detail:

1. No aspx controls are used.
2. In fact code-behind reads html file, fills data from the database and writes the final `html` to the response.

I understand code-behind methods are testable, but how? Any tools? Can you provide some reference please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Bacisally code-behind should not contains any heavy logic. Code behind should be aware of UI controls initialization, updating UI by handling events and so on.

I would suggest extracting functional units into separate classes and then just test these classes itself. In you case I see at least two standalone and abstracted functional units:

1. Data Access Layer
2. HTML Writer

If you are looking for testing UI behavioud you can use specisl frameworks like [WatiN](http://watin.org/):

> Inspired by Watir development of WatiN started in December 2005 to
>   make a similar kind of Web Application Testing possible for the .Net
>   languages. Since then WatiN has grown into an easy to use, feature
>   rich and stable framework. WatiN is developed in C# and aims to bring
>   you an easy way to automate your tests with Internet Explorer and
>   FireFox using .Net

**EDIT:** Answer to comments

- Generally data access helpers and services are located in a separate assembly and abstracted by interfaces so easily could be substituted and tested
- I like the approach when each project has own separate tests project, basically if you will stick with separate project `DataAccessLayer` - all related tests would be great to place in the separate `DataAccessLayer.Tests` project

Comment: Since I am dealing with an existing website, do you have any suggestions how to organize those separate classes (move to APP_CODE or separate DLLs)? Also, where do my Test classes stay? Thanks.

Comment: @user259760 : see EDIt part of my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at MVP (Model-View-Presenter) pattern for ASP.NET Web Forms. I am also in the process of rewriting a web site which did not use MVP.

Here are a few links:

- [Code Project - Model View Presenter with ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/ModelViewPresenter.aspx)
- [MSDN Magazine - Model View Presenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx)
- [Code Project - Building an MVP Framework for .NET. Part 1: The Basics of MVC and MVP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/DotNetMVPFramework_Part1.aspx)

I hope this will help you. Also, if you get a chance to read Dino Esposito's [Programming Microsoft ASP.NET 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735643385) you will find a nice chapter that explains MVP in details.

Comment: As I mentioned we are in the process of rewriting. That's going to take a while, in the mean time we want to start testing framework integrated with existing website. Do you have any other thoughts (since you are also in the same state)? Thanks.